# Does std::unordered_set allow insertion of duplicate elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

I am not understanding something right. I am under the impression that an unordered_set will not allow duplicate elements, based on their hash.

I have a struct, with a specialisation of std::hash, which appears to allow duplicates, although I have manually checked it

```
AddEdge ( const std::shared_ptr<Relation> relation, const std::shared_ptr<Concept> concept )
{
    auto edge = std::make_shared<Edge>( (Edge){ relation, concept } );
    auto res = _edges.insert ( edge );
    return res.second;
}
```

An overloaded function does exactly the same but for reversed parameters

This is how struct Edge is hashed:

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<shared_ptr<Edge>>
    {
        size_t operator()( const shared_ptr<Edge> & ptr ) const
        {
            size_t from = 0;
            size_t to = 0;

            if ( auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Concept>( ptr->from ) )
                from = hash<shared_ptr<Concept>>()( node );

            else if ( auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Relation>( ptr->from ) )
                from = hash<shared_ptr<Relation>>()( node );

            if ( auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Concept>( ptr->to ) )
                 to = hash<shared_ptr<Concept>>()( node );

            else if ( auto node = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Relation>( ptr->to ) )
                 to =  hash<shared_ptr<Relation>>()( node );

            return hash<size_t>()( from + to );
        }
    };
}
```

And the container held in:

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Edge>> _edges;
```

When I do:

```
graph2->AddEdge( sea_node, is_node );
graph2->AddEdge( is_node, blue_node );
```

I get:

```
Edge [sea,is] hash = 10017731961838884781
Edge [is,blue] hash = 11178184051384786808
```

I try a second time exactly the same, and I get the same hashes, yet, when I check the edges, I now have 4 edges instead of 2.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: class Concept & Relation have the same kind of hash function:

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<shared_ptr<Concept>>
    {
        size_t operator()( const shared_ptr<Concept> & ptr ) const
        {
            return hash<string>()( ptr->asToken()->value() ) + hash<int>()( ptr->TokenIndex() ) + hash<string>()( "Concept" );
        }
    };
}
```

Even more interestignly, my output from when I add Edges, produces the same hash, and yet it the duplicate Edge is added.

Comment: Let's see a [testcase](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: The pointers I am hashing, have exactly the same hash functions (see Edit). Unfortunately I can't create a testcase, too many classes involved for a small self contained example.

Comment: The entire point of creating a testcase is to _abstract away_ or _remove_ those classes. It is never impossible to construct a small, self-contained example, unless your problem relies on highly localised factors such as special hardware or insane heisenbugs. You should have done it as one of the first steps of your own debugging, long before asking for help... How are we or even you to know for sure that all those "too many classes" are not causing the problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair point, however its implied that the problem isn't in those classes, as I can clearly see the same hash being added more than once (I can add the output if you want). So, in this case it was my misunderstanding of the underlying mechanisms...

Comment: [Here's your testcase](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2006a409559d66b), no? Much better than dribs and drabs of random bits of output that you've hand picked! :) Please read the webpage I linked you to on why SSCCEs are expected here and more generally in the art of debugging. It would also leave the question far more useful for future visitors, which is 75% of why we are here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> an unordered_set will not allow duplicate elements, based on their hash

No, `unordered_set` avoids duplicates by comparing *values*, not the hashes of those values<sup>†</sup>.
The "values" of each of your shared pointers is going to differ because they refer to different objects.

You can actually change this behaviour by providing your own function as the `KeyEqual` template parameter to `unordered_set`:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,           // <-- you've been looking at this
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,   // <-- instead of this
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class unordered_set;
```

<sub><sup>†</sup> If only one value with a given hash were allowed in an `unordered_set` then (a) you'd be unable to add any values that genuinely resulted in hash collisions, and (b) the entire hash collision resolution mechanism would become entirely unnecessary.</sub>

Comment: I may have to read this a few times to digest it. Thanks for the explanation. So, should I be implementing std::equal_to<Edge> or does that not make sense?

Comment: @Alex: I guess it would be `std::equal_to<std::shared_ptr<Edge>>` but I really think your code is going to be very confusing to read and use when you have all this transparent dereferencing going on. Up to you I suppose. At the very least I'd pass your `Hash` and `KeyEqual` functors as template arguments to your set type, instead of making these implementations generally available to all of your code.

Comment: @Alex Note that `equal_to` must be implemented consistently with `hash`, that is if `equal_to(ptr1, ptr2)` then `hash(ptr1) == hash(ptr2)`